# Time format in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have no idea how i can format time in ActiveAdmin.
This is my index list:

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :book
    column :user
    column :time
    actions
  end
```

How can i format field :time as %H:%i:%s? Is it possible.
I need something like:

```
:format => :short
```

Answer (score 3):

In `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, look for [`localize_format`](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#localize-format-for-dates-and-times):

`config.localize_format = '%H:%i:%s'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it every where then modify the format in config/locale/en.yml like so

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

else for just your present column then do

```
column(:time) { |time| object.time.strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }
```

Comment: When i change time.formats.long does working but i need time.formats.short :)

undefined method `strftime' for #<Result:0x007fd8a9867750>

Answer (score 1):

The Good way: Use a decorator.

The Poor way: `column (:time) {|obj| obj.time.to_s(:short)}`

**With a decorator**  (create a decorators directory)

`app/decorators/results_decorator.rb`

```
class ResultsDecorator
  def intialize(result)
    @result = result
  end

  def time
    unless @result.time.nil?
      @result.time.to_s(:short)
    end
  end
end
```

`app/admin/result.rb`

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :book
  column :user
  column ('Time') {|result| ResultsDecorator.new(result).time }
  actions
end
```

Comment: Better off writing a decorator. http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-decorators  Try to handroll one yourself.

Comment: @franek100milionow I have given you an example of how you can handroll a decorator. You could use it as a template and push all your view logics into something similar, so that your code will be more testable and thus more maintainable.

Comment: Instead of manually decorating everywhere you can specify a decorator via `decorate_with` (see https://activeadmin.info/11-decorators.html).